# Win11 -- Screen saver no longer working since update

Tags: screensaver, lock-screen

Note: This thread is about Screen Saver functionality.

I rely on my screen saver to turn my computer into a picture frame (it goes through a folder of photos).

This worked fine for years. I think the recent windows update killed it.

Now, whether I am logged in OR even if the screen is locked (via Win-L), the screen saver *never* comes on.  Also the computer *never* locks itself.

I check the lock and screen saver settings and they are all as expected.

What to do next.

Comment: Which screen saver is that?

Comment: **If** you can't fix it, use a third-party tool such as IrfanView: https://beebom.com/best-photo-viewers-windows-10/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I am talking about screen saver functionality. IrfanView has screen saver functionality?  (OP also enhanced)

Comment: Yes, IrfanView does slideshows. It 's more flexible than the Windows version.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you! The good news: I learned that irfanview can make .scr files, which is news to me. The bad news: It appears the .scr cannot be a dynamic, random presentation of a directory of images (which I require). From my research so far, the .scr file is a static collection. I require dynamic and randomized.